# "rankear" array em Python

Tags: python, array

Estou com um problema e não estou conseguindo resolver, é o seguinte eu tenho uma lista de lista do tipo :

> ['Palavras', 4], ['evidenciaram', 3], ['apresentado', 2],
>   ['mostraram', 2], ['segundo', 1], ['tratados', 1], ['realizada', 1]

Onde o primeiro termo é a palavra e o segundo a repetição da mesma em um texto qualquer, o algoritmo já me retorna em ordem decrescente a quantidade de repetições agora eu preciso rankear, ou seja dizer que por exemplo `['palavras',4]` é o termo que mais repete ou seja ele é o 1° e 
`['tratados', 1]`, `['realizada', 1]` seria nesse caso o 4° colocado(ambos na mesma posição porque tem a mesma quantidade de repetições) por exemplo, eu queria que se possível tivesse um retorno do tipo

`['palavra','repetição','lugar do rankig']`, estou a horas tentando mas não consigo imaginar como fazer.

Trecho do código onde é gerado:

```
for key,value in reversed(sorted(self.frequency.items(),key=itemgetter(1))):
  self.palavras.append([key,value])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos começar por ordenar a lista:

```
lista = [['segundo', 1], ['evidenciaram', 3],['Palavras', 4], ['apresentado', 2], ['tratados', 1], ['realizada', 1], ['mostraram', 2]]
l_sorted = sorted(lista, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True) # ordenamos pelo segundo elemento de cada sublista e invertemos a ordem
print(l_sorted) # [['Palavras', 4], ['evidenciaram', 3], ['apresentado', 2], ['mostraram', 2], ['segundo', 1], ['tratados', 1], ['realizada', 1]]
```

Agora vamos tratar de adicionar a cada sublista o seu lugar no ranking (explicações em comentário no código abaixo):

```
rank = 1
l_sorted[0].append(rank) # adicionamos o rank 1 a primeira sublista visto que nao vale a pena faze-lo dentro do ciclo
for i in range(len(l_sorted)-1):
    if(l_sorted[i][1] != l_sorted[i+1][1]): # comparamos as repeticoes currentes com as seguintes e adcionamos 1 ao rank caso sejam diferentes
        rank += 1
    l_sorted[i+1].append(rank) # adicionamos a sublista seguinte o rank correspondente
print(l_sorted) # [['Palavras', 4, 1], ['evidenciaram', 3, 2], ['apresentado', 2, 3], ['mostraram', 2, 3], ['segundo', 1, 4], ['tratados', 1, 4], ['realizada', 1, 4]]
```

Em que o ultimo elemento de cada sublista é o seu lugar no ranking.

Código completo:

```
lista = [['segundo', 1], ['evidenciaram', 3],['Palavras', 4], ['apresentado', 2], ['tratados', 1], ['realizada', 1], ['mostraram', 2]]
l_sorted = sorted(lista, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

rank = 1
l_sorted[0].append(rank)
for i in range(len(l_sorted)-1):
    if(l_sorted[i][1] != l_sorted[i+1][1]):
        rank += 1
    l_sorted[i+1].append(rank)
# l_sorted = [['Palavras', 4, 1], ['evidenciaram', 3, 2], ['apresentado', 2, 3], ['mostraram', 2, 3], ['segundo', 1, 4], ['tratados', 1, 4], ['realizada', 1, 4]]
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/L3CW)

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou aqui, abraço!